# Multiple spheres from imported data

Tags: graphics, geometry

I have the centers, radius, and xyz-coordinates of say 200 spheres that I'd like to plot in a box. I know how to do one sphere using this information and `Graphics3D`, but do not know how to efficiently draw all 200.

How can I do it?

Comment: In principle, you will want to `Map` the `Sphere` command over the list of centers, radii, etc. Can you show us the exact format of your data? Also, what do you mean by xyz coordinated? A sphere is already uniquely determined by its center and radius.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I get my data from running a post-processing script in MATLAB - so the format is flexible. I plan on importing four different arrays from MATLAB into MATHEMATICA: Arry1=x coordinates of the center, Arry2=y coordinates of the center, Arry3=z coordinates of the center, Arry4=radii. The mapping is exactly my problem here. How do i pass on the information to Graphics3D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

After you clarified the format of your data that is imported in four arrays, here is a modified approach. Again, I will generate some fake data to play with:

```
array1 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 10]; (* = imported x coords *)
array2 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 10]; (* = imported y coords *)
array3 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 10]; (* = imported z coords *)
array4 = RandomReal[2, 10];         (* = imported radii    *)
```

You can then generate your `Sphere` expressions using `MapThread` (the cleaner, more readable choice, as suggested by J.M. below):

```
spheres = MapThread[Sphere[{#1, #2, #3}, #4] &, {array1, array2, array3, array4}];
```

or alternatively by explicit application, which was my first attempt:

```
spheres = Sphere[{#1, #2, #3}, #4] & @@@ Transpose[{array1, array2, array3, array4}];
```

---

Generate some play data for 10 random spheres in the form `{{centerX, centerY, centerZ}, radius}`:

```
spheredata = Transpose@{RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {10, 3}], RandomReal[2, 10]}
```

The generate `Sphere` objects from each of them and feed them to `Graphics3D`:

```
Graphics3D[
  Sphere @@@ spheredata
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Additionally if all the spheres had equal radii, then `Sphere[(* point list *), (* radius *)]` suffices.

Comment: OK, got it by manipulating your example. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user147813 I have just posted a modification of my answer for your format, but if you got it to work on your own already already, even better! Glad to help!

Comment: I'd have done it as `spheres = MapThread[Sphere[{#1, #2, #3}, #4] &, {array1, array2, array3, array4}];` myself.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, that's cleaner. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: One more question - I import my arrays as e.g. array1=Import["xcoor.txt","List"] but Graphics3D gives an error regarding the coordinates - says it should be a tripled of numbers or saled form - and also for the radius argument - says it should be a number or a list of numbers. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: What does `array1` look like after the import, @user?

Comment: It is {a1,a2,a3,...,a1100}. Could it be the size? is there a size limit? I have 1100 spheres...

Comment: @user No the size won't matter. Could you share exactly what code you are using to generate the spheres after you import the arrays?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't the size. I did figure out my coding mistake (sorry for the late update).

Comment: @user147813 No problem, thanks for the update anyway. If you think that my answer above provided an adequate solution to your problem, I'd appreciate it if you would consider accepting it. You can do so by clicking on the grey check mark next to the answer.